# Add missing months to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, resampling

I've seen plenty of examples and I can't make them work on my table. I have this table:

```
data = {'ID': ['Tom', 'Tom','Tom','Joseph','Joseph','Ben','Ben','Eden','Tim','Adam'], 'Tranche': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Blue'],'Totals':[100,100,100,50,50,90,90,70,60,70],'Sent':['2022-01-18','2022-02-19','2022-03-14','2021-04-14','2021-04-22','2022-03-03','2022-02-07','2022-01-04','2022-01-10','2022-01-15'],'Amount':[20,10,14,34,15,60,25,10,10,40],'Opened':['2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2021-03-23','2021-03-23','2021-12-19','2021-12-19','2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2021-12-29']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df["Opened"] = df["Opened"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df["Sent"] = df["Sent"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['SentMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sent']).dt.to_period('M')
```

[image]

I want every ID to have every SentMonth, with amount zero if there is no amount (fillna will do if I can get to that point). I need this to make a later .cumsum() give correct results.

e.g. for Tom, the output should be something like this, but just more rows with more SentMonths. The day in the Sent column does not matter - but there must be one row for every month:
[image]

First solution that is always given is reindexing. I can't do this as every SentMonth is duplicated, and Sent will also always have duplicates in my full table.

`df.resample('M').sum()`  gives the error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'.
Which I tried to fix by doing

```
df1 = df.set_index('SentMonth').groupby('ID').resample('1D')['Amount'].ffill()
```

But this brings me back to the unique index error.

Is there any other approach that can get around this? Thanks! :)

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: I'd have to add 11 rows for every ID - I would like every person to have a row for every month of 2022, with the same Tranche, totals etc and only Amount being different (set to zero).

Comment: id, tranche, totals are the same; sent column has multiple different dates

Comment: add a sample expected output dataframe for tom, that should suffice

Comment: Example added. Basically I need to have one row for every month of the year, and if there isn't one then it should be added with Amount=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a solution:

```
month_range = df["SentMonth"].unique()
df_per_user = dict()
for user_id, user_df in df.groupby("ID"):
    user_df.set_index("SentMonth", inplace=True)
    duplicated_rows = user_df.index.duplicated()
    if duplicated_rows.any():
        keep_rows = user_df[duplicated_rows]
        user_df = user_df[~duplicated_rows]

    df_per_user[user_id] = user_df.reindex(month_range).sort_index()

    if duplicated_rows.any():
        df_per_user[user_id] = pd.concat([df_per_user[user_id], keep_rows]).sort_index()

all_df = pd.concat(df_per_user)
all_df["Amount"] = all_df["Amount"].fillna(0)
all_df.fillna(method="bfill", axis=0, inplace=True)
all_df = all_df.reset_index().drop("level_0", axis=1)
all_df = all_df[df.columns] # restore original column order
```

So you have to take care for the ID with duplicated SentMonth (Joseph). The result looks like:

```
        ID Tranche  Totals       Sent  Amount     Opened SentMonth
0     Adam    Blue    70.0 2022-01-15     0.0 2021-12-29   2021-04
1     Adam    Blue    70.0 2022-01-15    40.0 2021-12-29   2022-01
2      Ben    Blue    90.0 2022-02-07     0.0 2021-12-19   2022-02
3      Ben    Blue    90.0 2022-02-07     0.0 2021-12-19   2022-03
4      Ben    Blue    90.0 2022-02-07     0.0 2021-12-19   2021-04
5      Ben    Blue    90.0 2022-02-07     0.0 2021-12-19   2022-01
6      Ben    Blue    90.0 2022-02-07    25.0 2021-12-19   2022-02
7      Ben    Blue    90.0 2022-03-03    60.0 2021-12-19   2022-03
8     Eden     Red    70.0 2022-01-04     0.0 2021-12-29   2021-04
9     Eden     Red    70.0 2022-01-04    10.0 2021-12-29   2022-01
10  Joseph    Blue    50.0 2021-04-14     0.0 2021-03-23   2022-02
11  Joseph    Blue    50.0 2021-04-14     0.0 2021-03-23   2022-03
12  Joseph    Blue    50.0 2021-04-14    34.0 2021-03-23   2021-04
13  Joseph    Blue    50.0 2021-04-22    15.0 2021-03-23   2021-04
14     Tim     Red    60.0 2022-01-10     0.0 2021-12-29   2022-01
15     Tim     Red    60.0 2022-01-10     0.0 2021-12-29   2022-02
16     Tim     Red    60.0 2022-01-10     0.0 2021-12-29   2022-03
17     Tim     Red    60.0 2022-01-10     0.0 2021-12-29   2021-04
18     Tim     Red    60.0 2022-01-10    10.0 2021-12-29   2022-01
19     Tom     Red   100.0 2022-01-18     0.0 2021-12-29   2022-02
20     Tom     Red   100.0 2022-01-18     0.0 2021-12-29   2022-03
21     Tom     Red   100.0 2022-01-18     0.0 2021-12-29   2021-04
22     Tom     Red   100.0 2022-01-18    20.0 2021-12-29   2022-01
23     Tom     Red   100.0 2022-02-19    10.0 2021-12-29   2022-02
24     Tom     Red   100.0 2022-03-14    14.0 2021-12-29   2022-03
```

Comment: Thank you, that does avoid pitfalls with more than one amount in the same sentmonth! I can do fillna(0) with Amount easily enough, but is there a way to fill the other columns with the correct IDs, Tranches etc?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can do that

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to expose missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# build a sequence of periods from the 1st month in 2022: 
periods={'SentMonth':pd.period_range('2022-01', '2022-12', freq='M')}

#Build the new dataframe:
out = (df
       .complete(('ID','Tranche','Totals', 'Opened'), periods)
       .fillna({'Amount':0}, downcast='infer')
       )
# you can change this, since `Sent` is not important
out.Sent = out.Sent.fillna(out.SentMonth.astype('datetime64[ns]'))
out

        ID Tranche  Totals       Sent  Amount     Opened SentMonth
0      Tom     Red     100 2022-01-18      20 2021-12-29   2022-01
1      Tom     Red     100 2022-02-19      10 2021-12-29   2022-02
2      Tom     Red     100 2022-03-14      14 2021-12-29   2022-03
3      Tom     Red     100 2022-04-01       0 2021-12-29   2022-04
4      Tom     Red     100 2022-05-01       0 2021-12-29   2022-05
..     ...     ...     ...        ...     ...        ...       ...
69    Adam    Blue      70 2022-10-01       0 2021-12-29   2022-10
70    Adam    Blue      70 2022-11-01       0 2021-12-29   2022-11
71    Adam    Blue      70 2022-12-01       0 2021-12-29   2022-12
72  Joseph    Blue      50 2021-04-14      34 2021-03-23   2021-04
73  Joseph    Blue      50 2021-04-22      15 2021-03-23   2021-04

[74 rows x 7 columns]
```

You can sort the dates in ascending/descending order